# problems with ajax when using select nested with php mvc

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am new to this community and I registered for a precise problem.

I am working with mvc in php with mysql as bd, for each table I have created a raw where I read, create, edit and delete the records from the database, my question is the following, I have a PRODUCT table where I incorporate foreign keys to another table called SUBITEM where it has a foreign key to ITEM. Returning to the CRUD of the PRODUCT table at the time of creating a new record, I must enter the heading through a  in html and depending on what is selected, load the second  which is SUBITEM, for that I am using AJAX that to Through a POST method with a JSON data type, it sends the id to a script in php and it returns the values ​​filtered by the ID through a mysql query, which would then be passed to json with json_encode. the issue that throws me error "insert: 131 text status =: parsererror, error thrown: = SyntaxError: Unexpected token

ajax code that is in insert.php, is the view where the product is loaded

```
$.ajax({
    data: { id : alumnos.val() },
    url:   'data.php',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type:  'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () 
    {
        item.prop('disabled', true);
    },
    success:  function (data) 
    {
        item.prop('disabled', false);

        // Limpiamos el select
        subitem.find('option').remove();

       $(data).each(function(i, v){ // indice, valor
            subitem.append('<option value="' + v.id + '">' + v.name + '</option>');
        })

        subitem.prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
       console.log('text status=:' + textStatus + ', error thrown:=' +  errorThrown);
       console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        item.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

data.php is the same hierarchical level with insert.php

```
include('../controllers/subitems.php');

    $subitem = $this->subitem_model->getSubitemByItem($_POST['id']);
    print_r(json_encode($data));
```

everything seems that the problem is due to the url address and that is why it automatically returns to the index through the .htaccess PD: I use sublimeText3 and xampp.

Comment: You should check in your browsers developement tools where the call is heading and if this is the correct url. If there is a problem, it would be helpful to include your .htaccess file in your question. Also note that you should not use print_r to output your json code. Also $data is never defined in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for your reply. the address is ok I have tried it in ajax returning .html, the issue when I use json, I don't know if I do the conversion well. To the json_encode () I send an object, I don't know if it will be ok? or in necessary an array